# Xamarin or Intel XDK for iOS/Android/Windows 8 smartphone business app?

Tags: html, mobile, gps, xamarin, smartphone

I am very aware of the masses of questions and posts around differing approaches and software products used to create a cross-platform mobile app. Rather than ask a general question mine is specific. Which of the two products mentioned would be best suited to my requirements?

My needs are straightforward. I need to produce this app quickly and at little cost. It does however need to be reliable and cross-platform. The app is for use within a business only and as such there is less emphasis on rigidly conforming to each platform's UI (although this does not negate the importance of UI design) - so something like Kendo UI would be fine.

The apps main purpose is to collect the phone's GPS position and pass that every 2 seconds to our server which will plot the location on a Google map. The GPS positioning requirement is therefore crucially important, so is the ability for the app to reliably 'call home' and pass the lats and longs via a web service call.

For all  of the reasons above I believe a hybrid application is the way forward. I realise this will have a small impact on speed of the application but I don't anticipate this will be problem. In my evaluation of potential development products I feel most comfortable with either Xamarin or Intel XDK.

Intel XDK seems the fastest to 'dive into' and the lower cost option (I don't believe I have to pay the per user costs if this is not commercial), however, considering my requirements, will I be missing any significant capability if I chose this over Xamarin?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Intel XDK should accomplish your need, for app UI you can use [Intel AppFramework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) which supports mobile UI conforming to each platform including iOS, iOS7, Android, Windows Phone 8 and others.